# Adding form in Ez Publish

Tags: ezpublish

How can i add a custom form in ez publish cms

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want from that form. You can create custom content class and set some attributes as information collectors.

Or you can hardcoded form in template.

But everything depends on what you want from that form.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Create eZ Publish Forms : Full tutorial](http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/how-to-create-ez-publish-forms)

Alternatively, you can setup and embed a Google docs form, and just create a TextBlock datatype field in your class (+ set up raw output in your view template) to allow your editors to create and insert their own Google docs forms.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an inbuilt Feedback form content class which you can copy and modify. In fact, every content-class in the CMS is customisable and an editable object, via a form from the website front-end or from admin. 
But I'm guessing that the Feebback Form content type is what you probably want. Go to Setup -> Classes -> Content -> feedback form
usually at yourdomain.com/admin_siteaccess/class/view/19

Answer (score 0):

Although [eZ Survey](http://projects.ez.no/ezsurvey_ezp4) is not the ideal and best way to use contact forms, it works.  My company uses it and it was designed for surveys and not forms.  Oh well.